# How to run bash commands inside of a Python script

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to run both Python and bash commands in a bash script.
In the bash script, I want to execute some bash commands enclosed by a Python loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

python << END
for i in range(1000):
    #execute‬ some bash command such as echoing i
END
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 41):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), e.g.:

```
import subprocess
# ...

subprocess.call(["echo", i])
```

There is another function like `subprocess.call`: `subprocess.check_call`. It is exactly like call, just that it throws an exception if the command executed returned with a non-zero exit code. This is often feasible behaviour in scripts and utilities.

`subprocess.check_output` behaves the same as `check_call`, but returns the standard output of the program.

---

**If you do not need shell features (such as variable expansion, wildcards, ...), never use shell=True** (shell=False is the default). *If* you use shell=True then shell escaping is your job with these functions and they're a security hole if passed unvalidated user input.

The same is true of os.system() -- it is a frequent source of security issues. Don't use it.

Comment: Why is not recommendable to use import os?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez, `os.system()` provides less control than the `subprocess.Popen` interface -- most importantly, it provides no way to pass data out-of-band from code (or to provide a literal argv array), making it hard to avoid shell injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @dom0, `shell=True` is the wrong thing for your `subprocess.call(["echo", i], shell=True)` example: The shell script that's run is just `echo`, with no arguments, and the `i` is passed as an argument to the shell that the script doesn't refer to.

Comment: I edited the answer so as to propose the secure way first.

Answer (score 18):

Look in to the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. There is the Popen method and some wrapper functions like `call`.

- If you need to check the output (retrieve the result string):

  ```
  output = subprocess.check_output(args ....)
  ```
- If you want to wait for execution to end before proceeding:

  ```
  exitcode = subprocess.call(args ....)
  ```
- If you need more functionality like setting environment variables, use the underlying Popen constructor:

  ```
  subprocess.Popen(args ...)
  ```

Remember subprocess is the higher level module. It should replace legacy functions from OS module.

Answer (score 1):

I used this when running from my IDE (PyCharm).

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('mybashcommand', shell=True)
```