# Python (3.4) run SSH commands on local terminal

Tags: python, ssh, terminal

I'm writing a script that I'm running through a terminal, and would like it to run BASH commands in that same terminal. All solutions that I found were geared toward connecting remotely through SSH, whereas I just need to run SSH commands on the same machine.

Can someone please point in a direction how that can be done, since Googling didn't really give me relevant results.

Comment: Exit out of Python and into the SSH shell? Or use the `subprocess` family of functions to spawn a shell.

Comment: I would try using different wording in your google search, because I know there are already answers to this questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236126/how-to-run-bash-command-inside-python-script

Comment: do you want to use ssh from python or you just want to run commands from python

Comment: I need to run BASH commands within the Python script. I read about subprocess, however all references to it were for external SSH connections. Will check on it in a bit. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Colonel Thirty Two, actually the end of my script would require to exit out of the Python script and run a Shell command using some variables from the script. Would that be possible with subprocess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) module.  You can do (for example):

```
subprocess.call("<bash command here>", shell = True)
```

For more details check the documentation.

Comment: When I checked earlier, all references to the subprocess module were for external SSH connections which would be unnecessary for my purpose. Since I can run BASH commands with it on the local machine without a connection, this is definitely the answer I was looking for. Thank you :)