# BASH and Python together

Tags: python

Very new to Python.

I have a Python script with a menu. At one selection, I want to start or call another script but it's BASH. The result is put in a text file in /tmp.
I want to do this:
Start Python script. At menu selection, have it start the BASH script. At end return back to Python script which processes the file in /tmp.
Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code

Comment: Duplicate of plenty of questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236126/how-to-run-bash-command-inside-python-script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, which is part the standard library.

> The `subprocess` module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.

In Unix systems, this means `subprocess` can spawn new Unix processes, execute their results, and fetch you back their output. Since a bash script is executed as a Unix process, you can quite simply tell the system to run the bash script directly.

A simple example:

```
import subprocess
ls_output = subprocess.check_output(['ls']) # returns result of `ls`
```

You can easily run a bash script by stringing arguments together. Here is a nice [example](http://sharats.me/the-ever-useful-and-neat-subprocess-module.html) of how to use `subprocess`.

All tasks in `subprocess` make use of [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) command, so it's worth understanding how that works. The Python docs offer this example of calling a bash script:

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Note the only important part is passing a list of arguments to `Popen()`.