# PyQt: How to execute shell command when a button clicked?

Tags: python, bash, qt, button, command

I have a QtGui and I want to execute a command for executing bash script "source base.bash" when button clicked.

Please answer using python code.

Comment: I assume you are using Linux.

Comment: yes I'm using linux

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
import os
os.system("xterm -hold -e scipt.sh")
```

Place this code in a function and link that function to button.

Comment: this one is worked 
os.system("xterm -e bash -c 'source base-station.bash; exec bash'")

Comment: I think you must have a look at this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236126/how-to-run-bash-command-inside-python-script