# Create a command-line in Ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, command-line

In Ubuntu, I'd like to create a command-line called `pycharm_help` which will open firefox or another browser with the website https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html. I know for doing this, I need to create a script with `#!/usr/bin` at the beginning. As I'm starting doing programming, I'd like that someone could help me to create this script in python. Could anyone be able to tell me how to do it? And help me create this little program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [How to run bash command inside python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26236126/3776858)

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus! I'd like someone to help me to construct this script.

Comment: see python module `webbrowser`. It can open web page using `webbrowser.open(url)`. It is standard module so you don't have to install it.

Comment: @furas Are you able to create that script?

Comment: first line: `#!/usr/bin/env python` , second line: `import webbrowser` , third line `webbrowser.open("https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html")` See doc: [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/webbrowser.html)

Comment: Ok good, I understand. If you put that as a full answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is standard module [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/webbrowser.html) to open page in default browser

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html")
```

If you have to open in `firefox` then maybe you will have to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webbrowser

browser = webbrowser.get('firefox')

browser.open("https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html")
```

---

**BTW:** Ubuntu will treat script as command-line command only if

- it has in first line `#!` with program which it has to use to execute this script
  (so called `"shebang"` or `"hashbang"` - `#` = she/hash, `!` = bang)
  ie. `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/python`
  (`#!/usr/bin/perl`, `#!/usr/bin/php`, etc.)
- it has "eXecution" privilage:

  ```
  chmod +x script.py
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a python script , you can follow the answer of @furas at comments.
But you can do it even in pure command line / bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdg-open "https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html" &
```

xdg-open calls the default web browser in your system.

Save the file (i.e charmhelp) under /usr/bin/ directory to be accesible from everywhere, then make it executable using `chmod +x /usr/bin/charmhelp` and you can run it when you need it as `charmhelp`

PS: If you save the file in other directory and you want to run it (i.e /name/home) you need to call it either by full path like `/name/home/charmhelp` or if you are already in name/home you have to run it as `./charmhelp` (mind the dot in the beginning).

You could also use links (terminal web browser) directly from terminal like

```
links -dump "https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html" |less
```

With links the web page will be displayed in terminal.

Much more simpler make an alias:

```
alias charmhelp='xdg-open https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html &'
```

runit by `charmhelp`. To make the alias permanent you have to put it in `name/home/.bashrc` file .

Comment: Thanks BTW, your answer is very well! I learnt stuff with that answer, but I wanted the answer in Python.