# How to preview pdf file in browser using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, preview

I want to preview a pdf file in browser then rename that file and then mail it to someone. Is it possible to do this with python script?

Comment: You might run the command from bash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236126/how-to-run-bash-command-inside-python-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module to use the browser

```
import webbrowser
new = 2 # open in a new tab, if possible

# open a public URL, in this case, the webbrowser docs
url = "http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html"
webbrowser.open(url,new=new)

# open an HTML file on my own (Windows) computer
url = "file://X:/MiscDev/language_links.html"
webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
```

Source of the example [here](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/how-to-open-a-web-browser-from-python/); documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html).
It should work the same way with Pdf files instead than html, if the browser can open them.

If you want to pause while you preview it, you can use

```
wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")
```

Renaming has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python), you use [os.rename(src, dst)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).

Emailing has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python), documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html).

Now put it all together!